# laravel Invoicing Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: laravel

I have installed a [package](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/laravel-invoices) for invoicing, but it shows `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. can anyone please help me.

Comment: It means your php script ran for 60 seconds and it have reached max_execution_time which specified in php.ini file you need to increase that or fix your php code to be faster than 60 seconds

Comment: i tried increasing the max_execution_time @AH.Pooladvand, but it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

add this function in your `public/index.php` file:

```
set_time_limit($seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try increase the `max_execution_time`  in `php.ini.` Set it to `1800` and restart your XAMPP.

But you should optimize your code to run it faster.